# Joi: filter values based on other key's value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi, hapi.js

I have a types list like below

```
const types = ['BAKERY', 'FRUITS', 'RESTAURANT', ...];
```

The length of this array is unknown. And i have a corresponding category list for each of the above mentioned types as mentioned below

```
const categories = {
  RESTAURANT: ['ADDON', 'AMERICAN', 'ANDHRA', ....],
  FRUITS: ['APPLE', 'BANANA', ....],
  RESTAURANT: ['VEG', 'NONVEG', ....],
};
```

I want to validate the schema of category based on the type selected.

```
const itemJoiSchema = Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string()
    .valid(...enums.types)
    .required(),
  category: Joi.string()
    .valid(............) // Here i want to accept only the values which fall into selected type above
    .uppercase()
    .required()
});
```

If i select `type: 'FRUITS',` then the category should only accept one out of `['APPLE', 'BANANA', ....],` and similarly for other categories as well.

I tried using refs but didn't worked. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using non-Joi solution, you can just access object value dynamically by key.

```js
const categories = {
  BAKERY: ['ADDON', 'AMERICAN', 'ANDHRA', ....],
  FRUITS: ['APPLE', 'BANANA', ....],
  RESTAURANT: ['VEG', 'NONVEG', ....],
};

const type = "FRUITS";

console.log(categories[type]); // ['APPLE', 'BANANA', ....],
```

So you can do:

```
// Example data to validate
const data = {
    type: "FRUITS",
    category: "APPLE"
};

// enums example:
const enums = {
    categories: {
        RESTAURANT: ['ADDON', 'AMERICAN', 'ANDHRA', ....],
        FRUITS: ['APPLE', 'BANANA', ....],
        RESTAURANT: ['VEG', 'NONVEG', ....],
    },
    types: ['BAKERY', 'FRUITS', 'RESTAURANT', ...]
}

const itemJoiSchema = Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string()
    .valid(...enums.types)
    .required(),
  category: Joi.string()
    .valid(...enums.categories[data.type] || []) 
    .uppercase()
    .required()
});
```

Since the `data.type` value is `"FRUITS"` it will pass `categories.FRUITS` as the valid array. The result will be equivalent to this

```
// Example data to validate
const data = {
    type: "FRUITS",
    category: "APPLE"
};

const itemJoiSchema = Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string()
    .valid(...enums.types)
    .required(),
  category: Joi.string()
    .valid(...['APPLE', 'BANANA', ....]) 
    .uppercase()
    .required()
});
```

Note: The `|| []` is to prevent error when the user is passing an incorrect `type`.

Working example: https://repl.it/repls/SuperAlienatedWorkplace. Change `data.type` value and you will see the valid category value changes accordingly

Comment: The type selection can be any one out of many right? So how your solution pick dynamic values for cateogry?

Comment: Yes it can be anything, for example `categories["FRUITS"]` is the equivalent to `categories.FRUITS`. I also had a typo on my answer, its supposed to be `.valid(...enums.categories[data.type] || []) `, not `.valid(...enums.categories[data.category] || [])`. This line is where you pass the valid category value based on the `data.type` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `.when()` method of Joi

Something like

```
const itemJoiSchema = Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string()
    .valid(enums.types)
    .required(),
  category: Joi.string()
    .when(type { is: 'FRUIT', then: joi.valid(categories.FRUIT })
    // etc
    .uppercase()
    .required()
});
```